# add each half xml child nodes inside separate divs

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xml:

```
<sitemapnode>
<node id="1"/>
<node id="2"/>
<node id="3"/>
<node id="4"/>
<node id="5"/>
<node id="6"/>
<node id="7"/>
<node id="8"/>
</sitemapnode>
```

I want to convert this into an html that looks something like;

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How do I iterate through all nodes and give divs and uls for each half of them separately?? Also if the number of nodes is odd, then ceiling can be done after halfing the number of nodes for first half. I am grappling with this since 3 days. And have yet not found any solution. Please Please Please help...

Here is the actual code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
<!-- The menu starts here. -->
    <ul class="nav" id="main-nav">
        <!-- Looping the sitemap nodes. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="siteMap/siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
            <!-- checking if the node is visible on top nav or not. -->     
            <xsl:if test="@isVisibleInTopnav = 'true'">
                <!-- Creating the L1 navigation. -->
                <li class="drop">
                    <a class="top_link">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <span>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@topNavTitle"/>
                        </span>                 
                    </a>
                    <!-- Creating the L2 navigation, L3 navigations..... -->
                    <div class="nav-sub">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <xsl:call-template name="nested_levels">    
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</div>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nested_levels">
    <xsl:param name="nodeCount" select="count(siteMapNode)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="ceiling($nodeCount div 2)"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(siteMapNode) > 0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="siteMapNode">
                            <xsl:if test="ceiling((position() - 1) div $columns) = (position() - 1) div $columns">  
                                <div class="row mod">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node|following-sibling::node[position() &lt; $columns]" mode="list" />
                                </div>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node" mode="list">
        <div>   <span class="h1">                       
                                    <a>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@topNavTitle"/>                               
                                    </a>
                                        </span>


        </div>
 </xsl:template>
```

and here is the sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode url="/" isVisibleInTopnav="" isVisibleInRightnav="" isVisibleInSitemap="" topNavTitle="" rightNavTitle="" hasBlueBackground="" showChildNav="" locatorKey="">
        <siteMapNode url="/a/" isVisibleInTopnav="true" isVisibleInRightnav="false" isVisibleInSitemap="true" topNavTitle="Personal Banking" rightNavTitle="" hasBlueBackground="false" showChildNav="false" locatorKey="">
            <siteMapNode url="/a/b/" isVisibleInTopnav="true" isVisibleInRightnav="true" isVisibleInSitemap="true" topNavTitle="Checking" rightNavTitle="Checking Accounts" hasBlueBackground="false" showChildNav="false" locatorKey="">
                <siteMapNode url="/a/b/c/" isVisibleInTopnav="true" isVisibleInRightnav="true" isVisibleInSitemap="false" topNavTitle="Checking Accounts" rightNavTitle="Compare Checking Accounts" hasBlueBackground="false" showChildNav="false" locatorKey="" />
            </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: Looks like homework. Could you provide some code, how you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: No. I could not write code that loops first 4 and then next for.

Comment: I am confused now, I am afraid! You have added a second XML sample, which differs quite a lot from the first sample. The first XML is a flat structure, but the second XML is nested. I am not clear what the expected output is for the second XML. It would be easier if you showed only one XML sample, and the expected output for that XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should not be thinking about iterating over all nodes. The approach you should take is to first get the count of half the number, and then get the nodes in the 1st and 5th (or whatever half is) position.

First to get the count of half the nodes you would create a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="ceiling(count(/*/node) div 2)" />
```

And then to get the relevant starting **node** elements, you would do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node[position() mod $number = 1]" />
```

Then, within this template, you output your **ul** element and then output the current element and the following three, like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="self::node|following-sibling::node[position() &lt; $number]" 
     mode="list" />
```

This will look for a union of two nodes. **self::node** will match the current node, and **following-sibling::node[position() < $number]** matches the next 3 siblings. Note that **position** is relative to the current element in this case.

Note the use of **mode** because otherwise you will have two templates matching the **node** element, so you need a way to distinguish between them. Without the **mode** element, and a different template for that mode, the **self::node** match will lead to infinite recursion.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="number" select="ceiling(count(/*/node) div 2)" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node[position() mod $number = 1]" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node|following-sibling::node[position() &lt; $number]" mode="list" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node" mode="list">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to correct my answer, and I was doing every fourth node, as opposed to halfing the elements.

Comment: Does position() work even when its not inside a loop. What will it return?  and please explain what will "self::node|following-sibling::node[position() &lt; $number]" do..

Comment: Please see the answer below. It has the code that I am using. Its not working but.

Comment: I've also expanded my answer to explain a bit more about the xpath expression to matcht the nodes.